# Toggle groups of markers in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have several groups ("state") of markers on a map which I want to be able to toggle their visibility without reloading the page.

I'm finding lots of variations of having markergroups but they all seem to be not working with this google api version.

Here is the HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="state" name="Backlog" checked> Backlog
<input type="checkbox" id="state" name="Breached" checked> Breached
<input type="checkbox" id="state" name="Active" checked> Active
<input type="checkbox" id="state" name="Scheduled" checked> Scheduled
<div id="map" style="height:800px;"></div>
```

Here is the javascript

```
<script>
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       zoom: 6,
        center: {lat: 54.3266311, lng: -2.7585563},
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });

    var infoWin = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/'+location.type,
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
            infoWin.setContent(location.info);
            infoWin.open(map, marker);
        })
        return marker;
    });

    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
            imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m',
            minimumClusterSize: 2,
            maxZoom: 4,
            zoomOnClick: false
        }
    );
}

var locations = [{lat:53.750503,lng:-2.429168,type:'/paddle/ylw-square-lv.png',state:'Backlog',info:"<strong>Order ID:</strong> 75199925"},{lat:51.290162,lng:-0.833112,type:'/paddle/ylw-square-lv.png',state:'Backlog',info:"<strong>Order ID:</strong> 76669845"},{lat:51.301737,lng:0.051969,type:'/paddle/ylw-square-lv.png',state:'Backlog',info:"<strong>Order ID:</strong> 75199930"},{lat:50.525378,lng:-3.594341,type:'/paddle/ylw-square-lv.png',state:'Backlog',info:"<strong>Order ID:</strong> 78875603"},{lat:51.581895,lng:-0.724800,type:'/paddle/ylw-square-lv.png',state:'Backlog',info:"<strong>Order ID:</strong> 78581052"},{lat:50.391133,lng:-4.072097,type:'/paddle/ylw-square-lv.png',state:'Backlog',info:"<strong>Order ID:</strong> 78106941"},{lat:51.318527,lng:-1.021035,type:'/paddle/ylw-square-lv.png',state:'Backlog',info:"<strong>Order ID:</strong> 78396115"},{lat:50.443925,lng:-3.561630,type:'/paddle/ylw-square-lv.png',state:'Backlog',info:"<strong>Order ID:</strong> 78875582"},{lat:53.625107,lng:-2.337432,type:'/paddle/blu-square-lv.png',state:'Active',info:"<strong>Order ID:</strong> 80444510"},{lat:52.432582,lng:-2.026563,type:'/paddle/blu-square-lv.png',state:'Active',info:"<strong>Order ID:</strong> 80423141"}]
```

Any help would be great :) I don't mind getting rid of the clusters, I just can't figure out how to!

Comment: Marker.className then JS to toggle the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. HTML element ids must be unique, all your checkboxes currently have the same id.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="state" name="Backlog" checked> Backlog
<input type="checkbox" id="state" name="Breached" checked> Breached
<input type="checkbox" id="state" name="Active" checked> Active
<input type="checkbox" id="state" name="Scheduled" checked> Scheduled
```

typically that is what "name" is used for (it is allowed to be the same), so you can do this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="state" id="Backlog" checked> Backlog
<input type="checkbox" name="state" id="Breached" checked> Breached
<input type="checkbox" name="state" id="Active" checked> Active
<input type="checkbox" name="state" id="Scheduled" checked> Scheduled
```

2. then when the checkboxes are clicked, process through the array of markers, setting the `visible` property appropriately:

```
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('Backlog'), 'click', clickListener);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('Breached'), 'click', clickListener);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('Active'), 'click', clickListener);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('Scheduled'), 'click', clickListener);

   function clickListener() {
       var typeId = this.id;
       var type;
       for (var i=0; i<iconMapping.length;i++) {
         if (iconMapping[i].state==typeId)
           type = iconMapping[i].icon;
       }
       var markers = markerCluster.getMarkers();
       for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
          if (markers[i].getIcon().includes(type)) {
             markers[i].setVisible(this.checked);
          }
       }
    }
}
// your example doesn't include examples for Active/Scheduled, if they are 
// duplicates of existing marker icons, a different approach will need to be used.
var iconMapping = [
{icon:'ylw-square-lv.png',state:'Backlog'},
{icon:'blu-square-lv.png',state:'Active'}
];
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/npob98d6/3/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map with one checkbox unchecked]

(if you want the clusters to reflect the currently visible icons, you will need to update the markers array passed in to it, rather than the `visible` property of the markers).

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: {
      lat: 54.3266311,
      lng: -2.7585563
    },
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });

  var infoWin = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/' + location.type,
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
      infoWin.setContent(location.info);
      infoWin.open(map, marker);
    })
    return marker;
  });

  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/images/m',
    minimumClusterSize: 2,
    maxZoom: 4,
    zoomOnClick: false
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('Backlog'), 'click', clickListener);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('Breached'), 'click', clickListener);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('Active'), 'click', clickListener);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('Scheduled'), 'click', clickListener);

  function clickListener() {
    var typeId = this.id;
    var type;
    for (var i = 0; i < iconMapping.length; i++) {
      if (iconMapping[i].state == typeId)
        type = iconMapping[i].icon;
    }
    var markers = markerCluster.getMarkers();
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      if (markers[i].getIcon().includes(type)) {
        markers[i].setVisible(this.checked);
      }
    }
  }
}
var iconMapping = [{
    icon: 'ylw-square-lv.png',
    state: 'Backlog'
  },
  {
    icon: 'blu-square-lv.png',
    state: 'Active'
  }
];
var locations = [{
  lat: 53.750503,
  lng: -2.429168,
  type: '/paddle/ylw-square-lv.png',
  state: 'Backlog',
  info: "<strong>Order ID:</strong> 75199925"
}, {
  lat: 51.290162,
  lng: -0.833112,
  type: '/paddle/ylw-square-lv.png',
  state: 'Backlog',
  info: "<strong>Order ID:</strong> 76669845"
}, {
  lat: 51.301737,
  lng: 0.051969,
  type: '/paddle/ylw-square-lv.png',
  state: 'Backlog',
  info: "<strong>Order ID:</strong> 75199930"
}, {
  lat: 50.525378,
  lng: -3.594341,
  type: '/paddle/ylw-square-lv.png',
  state: 'Backlog',
  info: "<strong>Order ID:</strong> 78875603"
}, {
  lat: 51.581895,
  lng: -0.724800,
  type: '/paddle/ylw-square-lv.png',
  state: 'Backlog',
  info: "<strong>Order ID:</strong> 78581052"
}, {
  lat: 50.391133,
  lng: -4.072097,
  type: '/paddle/ylw-square-lv.png',
  state: 'Backlog',
  info: "<strong>Order ID:</strong> 78106941"
}, {
  lat: 51.318527,
  lng: -1.021035,
  type: '/paddle/ylw-square-lv.png',
  state: 'Backlog',
  info: "<strong>Order ID:</strong> 78396115"
}, {
  lat: 50.443925,
  lng: -3.561630,
  type: '/paddle/ylw-square-lv.png',
  state: 'Backlog',
  info: "<strong>Order ID:</strong> 78875582"
}, {
  lat: 53.625107,
  lng: -2.337432,
  type: '/paddle/blu-square-lv.png',
  state: 'Active',
  info: "<strong>Order ID:</strong> 80444510"
}, {
  lat: 52.432582,
  lng: -2.026563,
  type: '/paddle/blu-square-lv.png',
  state: 'Active',
  info: "<strong>Order ID:</strong> 80423141"
}]
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 90%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Marker Clustering</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js"></script>

  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <input type="checkbox" name="state" id="Backlog" checked> Backlog
  <input type="checkbox" name="state" id="Breached" checked> Breached
  <input type="checkbox" name="state" id="Active" checked> Active
  <input type="checkbox" name="state" id="Scheduled" checked> Scheduled
  <div id="map"></div>

  <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap" async></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want the clusters to reflect the number of visible markers, you need to change the code to update the markers array in the `MarkerClusterer`:

```
function clickListener() {
   var typeId = this.id;
   var type;
   var visibleMarkers = [];
   for (var i=0; i<iconMapping.length;i++) {
     if (iconMapping[i].state==typeId)
       type = iconMapping[i].icon;
   }
   for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
      if (markers[i].getIcon().includes(type)) {
         markers[i].setVisible(this.checked);
      }
      if (markers[i].getVisible())
        visibleMarkers.push(markers[i]);
   }
   markerCluster.clearMarkers();
   markerCluster.addMarkers(visibleMarkers);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/npob98d6/5/)

[image: screenshot of clusters showing only visible markers]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: {
      lat: 54.3266311,
      lng: -2.7585563
    },
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });

  var infoWin = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/' + location.type,
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
      infoWin.setContent(location.info);
      infoWin.open(map, marker);
    })
    return marker;
  });

  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/images/m',
    minimumClusterSize: 2,
    maxZoom: 4,
    zoomOnClick: false
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('Backlog'), 'click', clickListener);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('Breached'), 'click', clickListener);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('Active'), 'click', clickListener);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('Scheduled'), 'click', clickListener);

  function clickListener() {
    var typeId = this.id;
    var type;
    var visibleMarkers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < iconMapping.length; i++) {
      if (iconMapping[i].state == typeId)
        type = iconMapping[i].icon;
    }
    console.log("click type=" + type)
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      console.log("markers[" + i + "] icon=" + markers[i].getIcon() + " map=" + markers[i].getMap() + "visible=" + markers[i].getVisible());
      if (markers[i].getIcon().includes(type)) {
        markers[i].setVisible(this.checked);
        console.log("markers[" + i + "] map=" + markers[i].getMap() + " visible=" + markers[i].getVisible())
      }
      if (markers[i].getVisible())
        visibleMarkers.push(markers[i]);
    }
    markerCluster.clearMarkers();
    console.log("after clear:" + markerCluster.getMarkers().length)
    markerCluster.addMarkers(visibleMarkers);
    console.log("after add:" + markerCluster.getMarkers().length)

  }
}
var iconMapping = [{
    icon: 'ylw-square-lv.png',
    state: 'Backlog'
  },
  {
    icon: 'blu-square-lv.png',
    state: 'Active'
  }
];
var locations = [{
  lat: 53.750503,
  lng: -2.429168,
  type: '/paddle/ylw-square-lv.png',
  state: 'Backlog',
  info: "<strong>Order ID:</strong> 75199925"
}, {
  lat: 51.290162,
  lng: -0.833112,
  type: '/paddle/ylw-square-lv.png',
  state: 'Backlog',
  info: "<strong>Order ID:</strong> 76669845"
}, {
  lat: 51.301737,
  lng: 0.051969,
  type: '/paddle/ylw-square-lv.png',
  state: 'Backlog',
  info: "<strong>Order ID:</strong> 75199930"
}, {
  lat: 50.525378,
  lng: -3.594341,
  type: '/paddle/ylw-square-lv.png',
  state: 'Backlog',
  info: "<strong>Order ID:</strong> 78875603"
}, {
  lat: 51.581895,
  lng: -0.724800,
  type: '/paddle/ylw-square-lv.png',
  state: 'Backlog',
  info: "<strong>Order ID:</strong> 78581052"
}, {
  lat: 50.391133,
  lng: -4.072097,
  type: '/paddle/ylw-square-lv.png',
  state: 'Backlog',
  info: "<strong>Order ID:</strong> 78106941"
}, {
  lat: 51.318527,
  lng: -1.021035,
  type: '/paddle/ylw-square-lv.png',
  state: 'Backlog',
  info: "<strong>Order ID:</strong> 78396115"
}, {
  lat: 50.443925,
  lng: -3.561630,
  type: '/paddle/ylw-square-lv.png',
  state: 'Backlog',
  info: "<strong>Order ID:</strong> 78875582"
}, {
  lat: 53.625107,
  lng: -2.337432,
  type: '/paddle/blu-square-lv.png',
  state: 'Active',
  info: "<strong>Order ID:</strong> 80444510"
}, {
  lat: 52.432582,
  lng: -2.026563,
  type: '/paddle/blu-square-lv.png',
  state: 'Active',
  info: "<strong>Order ID:</strong> 80423141"
}]
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 90%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Marker Clustering</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js"></script>

  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <input type="checkbox" name="state" id="Backlog" checked> Backlog
  <input type="checkbox" name="state" id="Breached" checked> Breached
  <input type="checkbox" name="state" id="Active" checked> Active
  <input type="checkbox" name="state" id="Scheduled" checked> Scheduled
  <div id="map"></div>

  <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&v=weekly&channel=2" async></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [setVisible](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Marker.setVisible) function in marker class like this:

```js
for (var i in markersToHide) {
    markersToHide[i].setVisible(true);
}

// if markers are inside a cluster
markerCluster.repaint();
```